# How can I increase the efficiency of this code to find the largest prime factor of 600851475143?

Tags: c, performance, prime-factoring

I want my program to find the largest prime factor of number 600851475143. For example, the prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29 and 29 is the largest one. While my code does work, the answer takes too long to appear even for much smaller inputs, such as 6kk (takes about 15 seconds. For 12kk, it takes 37 seconds, so the increments are even worse than linear), which is 100k times smaller than the number I should use as the input. Below is my code, any help concerning the increased efficiency of the code would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    long long int number=600851475143;
    int largest_prime_factor,i,j,k;
    for (i=1;i<number/2;i+=2){
         k=0;
         j=3;
         for (j=3;j<=sqrt(i);j+=2){
            if (i%j==0){
                k++;
                break;
              }
                }
        if (k==0){
            if (number%i==0)
                largest_prime_factor=i;
        }
    }
    printf("The largest prime factor of 600851475143 is: %d",  
    largest_prime_factor);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried until now, to increase performance? How do you compile your code?

Comment: This question is fine and on-topic, but please note that when you have questions about how to improve working code, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might give you better and more detailed answers.

Comment: If your code is working and you want to optimise it, this post should be on code review. Lundin said it first.

Comment: You can parallelize your code using something like OpenMPI !

Comment: Prime Factorization is suspected to be an NP hard problem ... I'm not quite sure how you want to keep it's time in a polynomial upper limit, without using considerable space...

Comment: Minor things I guess (I am a beginner). Used number/2 instead of number as i's ceiling and in order to verify whether each i's value is a prime or not, j reaches up to i's square root, instead of i/2 or even i itself. About your last question, I am not sure what you mean. Are there different ways of compiling a program which affect the program's running time till it finds an answer?

Comment: ***"warning: iteration 1073741823u invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]*** `largest_prime_factor` and `i` surely cannot be a plain `int`, as they have to keep numbers of the same magnitude of `number`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Do not say "surely" just because you have a 32 bit int. ;-). But of course for portable code it's essential to have a loop variable of the same type as the upper limit.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: here I am assuming that he chose wrote `long long int` for a reason and not only because he likes to type. :o)

Comment: Depending on compilation, `++k;` may be slightly better than `k++;`

Comment: @Toby: talking about integers, that's true probably on 30+ years old compilers :-) (talking about iterators and other complex objects instead is still useful advice).

Comment: Btw, I would factor out the primality test into its own function. That makes the code clearer and makes the algorithm easier to change (since it's the time bottleneck you may want to try more sophisticated ones). Then, use speaking variable names: "primeCandidate", "divisor", "isPrime" etc.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to go through the whole list. Once you find one prime factor, you factorize your number by that, and continue working with what's left.

For instance, take your example: 600,851,475,143. You can quickly find its first prime factor to be 71. If you divide 600,851,475,143 by 71 you get 8,462,696,833. Both these numbers share the same prime factors except 71. So now you can search the largest factor of the original number but with a search space reduced by 2 orders of magnitude.

Also, notice that your code will fail if the number itself is prime. To fix that, initialize your maximum number as

```
int largest_prime_factor = 1;
```

and if it's still 1 in the end, return the number itself. (You could initialize with `number`, but you'll soon see why I chose 1)

So start by treating 2 as a special case:

```
    long long remain = number;
    while (remain % 2 == 0) {
            remain /= 2;
            largest_prime_factor = 2;
    }
```

And then do it similarly inside your loop. Since for prime numbers we only need to check up to its square root, we'll limit our loop by two cases, depending on whether we still think the number could be prime.

1. Still prime: test up to sqrt(number)
2. No longer prime: test until the maximum factor exceeds what remains.

In the end, your modified code may look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   
    long long int number=600851475143;
    long long largest_prime_factor = 1,i,j,k;
    long long remain = number;

    while (remain % 2 == 0) {
        remain /= 2;
        largest_prime_factor = 2;
        /* Uncomment to see the factors 
           printf("2 ");*/
    }   

    for (i=3; (largest_prime_factor == 1 && i*i <= number) ||  
            (largest_prime_factor > 1&& i <= remain); i+=2){
        k=0;
        j=3;
        for (j=3; j*j<=i;j+=2){
            if (i%j==0){
                k++;        
                break;   
            }        
        }
        if (k==0 && remain%i==0) {
            largest_prime_factor=i;
            while (remain % i == 0) {
                /* Uncomment to see the factors 
                printf("%d ", i); */
                remain /= i;  
            }            
        }
    }
    printf("The largest prime factor of %Ld is: %Ld",
            number, largest_prime_factor);
    return 0;
}
```

Also notice that other variables should also be of type (long long).

The bottleneck will be checking if each number is prime, and the whole process will still be slow if the prime factors themselves are large. But you can get a much faster average case. For your example, this algorithm gets the factors 71, 839, 1471, and 6857 in less than a second.

Answer (score 2):

You should move `sqrt(i)` out of the for loop. It is calculated in every loop. Also `j*j <= i` would be much faster than `j <= sqrt(i)`.

There is an **error** in your code: if number is a `long long int` the other variables should be too or the condition `i<number/2` is always true!

Comment: Modern compilers should be able to optimize that. But indeed, on older compilers you definitely wanted to move calculations out of the loop condition.

Comment: Will GCC do that without explicit optimization flags?

Comment: Most compilers would optimize it if they could be sure the sqrt() function has no side effects. This may be true for some compilers, but not for all.
In my opinion it is generally a good idea to use squares instead of square roots if possible.

Comment: Also, `number` does not appear to be changed in the loop so why recalculate `number/2` on every loop? Do `number /= 2;` before the first `for`

Comment: What troubles me, is that when I declared the variables as long long ints instead of just ints, as you correctly advised me to do, nothing changed. The results remained the same. Doesn't an int reach up to 32k? Using 13456769 as the input gave me  708251 in both cases (13.456.769 is exactly 19 times bigger than 708.251, so the answer should be correct) + when I used long long int to declare the variables, the code became about 2 times slower.

Comment: The size of an integer is depending on the platform in use. Typically an integer has 16 or 32 bits and allowes values from -32768 to 32767 or -2.147.483.648 to 2.147.483.647. But the fact that your code actually finishes makes me think your machine is using 64-bit integers by default. Another possibility is that all math results are stored as integers so doing number/2 may cast from long long to int. This applies for 8- and 16-bit values. Not sure if it is true for 64-bit values.

Comment: Please take a look at my second answer. This code finds the prime factors in milliseconds: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40996934/6172310.

Comment: I did run your code. It's extremely fast, but for some reason it does not work for every input I use and I am sure that the way I tweaked it in order for it to run did not mess with the logic behind the code itself. When I use 13195, it does give me 29 f.e.,which is correct. Same goes for other inputs. But when I use 13.456.769,it gives 1 as the output (which normally is 708.251). Generally speaking, what I've noticed by running it maybe 20 times,is that it always works for smaller inputs. Thank you so much for this code! It's been of great help. I'll experiment on it now and see what happens.

Comment: Didn't notice you said you haven't checked it thoroughly before. My bad. And yes, the result I needed with that input was correct. Thanks again!

Comment: You need a larger primes-array for such huge prime factors. In C++ I am using a std::vector which dynamically allocates memory. I've added a C version with dynamic storage to my other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40996934/6172310

Answer (score 2):

In general, there is no efficient way to do this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Difficulty_and_complexity

There are ways to increase your code's speed though. Have a look at some of the algorithms in that article.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Not sure. It may be the most valuable answer, actually, because it points out the root cause of the OP's dissatisfaction with performance. Plus it points to hints that are less obvious (I suppose) than "move computations out of the for loop".

Comment: @MichaelWalz Keep it for posteriority... discussion can be instructive. Other ppl will have the same idea. Ah, too late ;-).

Comment: @MichaelWalz I went back and forth with whether to comment or answer. I decided on answer because there is no real way to get an efficient solution as far as computational complexity is concerned and outright code review is a separate problem for a separate site. Good arguments can be made for commenting too, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

This code should be pretty fast and only takes a few milliseconds for the number 600851475143:

```
long long int primes[1000];
int primesSize = 0;
long long int primeFactors[100];
int primeFactorsSize = 0;

long long int number = 600851475143ll;

for (long long int f = 2; f < number / 2; ++f)
{
    // Check if f is a prime number
    int primesIndex = 0;
    while (primesIndex < primesSize && (f%primes[primesIndex]) != 0)
        ++primesIndex;

    if (primesIndex >= primesSize)
    {
        primes[primesSize++] = f;

        // Check if f is a prime factor of number
        while ((number % f) == 0)
        {
            primeFactors[primeFactorsSize++] = f;
            number /= f;
        }
    }
}

if (number != 1)
    primeFactors[primeFactorsSize++] = number;
```

Creating a list of prime numbers already found speeds up the check of another possible factor.

If you find a prime factor of your number, you divide your number by the prime factor and continue with the division result. Perhaps this division has to be done multiple times. The final value in `number` also is the greatest prime factor.

Warning: My code has not been tested at all. I just made sure the result is correct for `number = 600851475143ll`. Also I am using a C++ compiler so you may have to make some minor changes.

For larger `number`s you need to implement dynamic memory allocation at least for the `primes` array:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long long int *primes = NULL;
    int primesSize = 0;
    int primesCapacity = 0;
    long long int *primeFactors = NULL;
    int primeFactorsSize = 0;
    int primeFactorsCapacity = 0;

    long long int number = 600851475143ll;
    number = 13456769ll;

    for (long long int f = 2; f < number / 2; ++f)
    {
        // Check if f is a prime number
        int primesIndex = 0;
        while (primesIndex < primesSize && (f%primes[primesIndex]) != 0)
            ++primesIndex;

        if (primesIndex >= primesSize)
        {
            if (primesSize == primesCapacity)
            {
                primesCapacity += 1000;
                primes = (long long int*)realloc(primes, primesCapacity * sizeof(long long int));
            }
            primes[primesSize++] = f;

            // Check if f is a prime factor of number
            while ((number % f) == 0)
            {
                if (primeFactorsSize == primeFactorsCapacity)
                {
                    primeFactorsCapacity += 1000;
                    primeFactors = (long long int*)realloc(primeFactors, primeFactorsCapacity * sizeof(long long int));
                }
                primeFactors[primeFactorsSize++] = f;
                number /= f;
            }
        }
    }

    if (number != 1)
    {
        if (primeFactorsSize == primeFactorsCapacity)
        {
            primeFactorsCapacity += 1000;
            primeFactors = (long long int*)realloc(primeFactors, primeFactorsCapacity * sizeof(long long int));
        }

        primeFactors[primeFactorsSize++] = number;
    }

    printf("Last prime factor is %lld", primeFactors[primeFactorsSize-1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using j*j<=i instead of j<=sqrt(i), depending on the magnitude of the numbers I used, made the code 5 to 10 times faster. ++k; instead of k++; had a slight impact as well. By about 0.5%. And I have not checked everything yet. Thank you everyone for your valuable inputs! There's lots of things to think and learn about thanks to them!